# CSS classes added in project.module.scss not showingUp in my .tsx file in SPFx Project

Tags: sharepoint-online, css, spfx, spfx-webparts, sharepoint-framework

Currently I started working on React SPFx webparts and wanted to add some new CSS.

I added some styling to classes in `Project.Module.scss`. But Now when I am adding this class names in `render()` method , it's saying Property `.tableStyle` does not exists.

According to some posts, SPFx converts this styles to data types and append unique code to `className` to keep them unique.

Now, If I add manually to `project.Module.scss.ts` and `project.Module.scss.d.ts` then only render() method taking this style classes.

As per some blogs, We don't have to make changes in other 2 files. Need Suggestion.

In following code, I have added `.test` class styling, whereas rest classes were already present in `.scss` file.

```
.reactScriptEditorWp {

  .test{
display: none;

  }

  .tableStyle{ 
    display:  table ;
    margin-left :  100px ;
  }
  .container {
    max-width: 700px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 25px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  }

  .row {
    @include ms-Grid-row;
    @include ms-fontColor-white;
    background-color: $ms-color-themeDark;
    padding: 20px;
  }

  .column {
    @include ms-Grid-col;
    @include ms-lg10;
    @include ms-xl8;
    @include ms-xlPush2;
    @include ms-lgPush1;
  }}
```

`project.tsx` file:

```
return ( 

      <div className={styles.reactScriptEditorWp} >
        <br></br>

        <br></br>
        <div className={styles.tableCaptionStyle} > Retrieve SharePoint List Items using SPFx , REST API  & React JS  </div>
        <br></br>
         <div className={styles.test} > Employee Details</div>
        <div className={styles.test} >  

          <div className={styles.test} > 
            <div className={styles.test}>Employee Name</div> 
            <div className={styles.test}>Employee Id </div> 
            <div className={styles.test}>Experience</div> 
              <div className={styles.test}>Location</div>                    
          </div> 
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is `{` missing in your `.scss` file also or it is just here because you have copy pasted it wrong.

Comment: Yes.. sorry I copy Pasted it wrong here. I Tried to paste part of the code rather than whole code

Answer (score 0):

If you have no errors, the css class name should become available on the tsx file after a build. If it doesn't, you can go to the definition of your imported styles and you should see the new class available. After this, the editor becomes aware of the new class.

To go to the styles definition, simply click on the "styles" word at the import and press F12.
import styles from './HelloWorldWebPart.module.scss';